# typeorm subscribers are fired before they are committed

Tags: postgresql, typeorm, subscriber

There are several issues on the typeorm repo regarding afterUpdate/afterInsert/etc s.t. the database entity is not persisted at the time the hook is called.
E.G. https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/6122

My use-case is to listen to the event on an updated/created entity, which then kicks off an event to another service using the ID/Status of the updated entity. The recipient service, now noticing a notification, will query for the most up-to-date information. This however, is stale, as the subscriber will wait until everything in the AfterUpdate/AfterInsert hook to completed before committing the result.

The recipient service will then act on old data as opposed to fresh data. Here is a flowchart of what I'm describing above:

Entity **Starts** the update --> AfterUpdate Hook executed --> Recipient Service notified --> Recipient service queries original service --> service returns stale data --> AfterUpdate Hook completes --> Entity gets **Committed**

Obviously this is less than ideal. Is there a way to use the subscribers as I've intended to use them? I would like to act on committed changes, not uncommitted changes.

"Solutions" that are listed on github repos are around using the same entity manager that is making the change. This does not work since I'm leaving my service to notify a client an update has happened and the client should get fresh data. Clients cannot get fresh data as the AfterUpdate/AfterInsert methods block until commit.

```
@EventSubscriber()
@Injectable()
export class MyEntitysSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<MyEntity> {

  constructor(
    private readonly connection: Connection,
    @Inject(PublisherService) private readonly publisherService: PublisherService,
    @Inject(LoggerService) private readonly logger: LoggerService,
  ) {
    connection.subscribers.push(this);
  }

  /**
     * Indicates that this subscriber only listen to MyEntity events.
     */
  listenTo(): any {
    return MyEntity;
  }

  /**
     * Called after MyEntity updates.
     */
  async afterUpdate(event: UpdateEvent<MyEntity>): Promise<void> {
    const { id: entityId, status: oldStatus } = event.databaseEntity;
    const newStatus = event.entity?.status;
    this.logger.info('my-entity-status-changed', {
      entityId,
      oldStatus,
      newStatus, //this status is not persisted in the database. If the client asks retrieves this entity during the lifecycle of this hook, it will get the oldStatus. 
    });
    await this.publisherService.publishMessage(newStatus, entityId);
  }
}
```

Update:

I saw this answer: [Queries in AfterUpdate are not working as expected in TypeORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62887344/queries-in-afterupdate-are-not-working-as-expected-in-typeorm?rq=1)

But it seems to feel like I'm hacking around a bug/the way typeorm lifecycle is intended to be used.